# Overriding <sup> styling

Tags: html, css

I'd like to ignore/override `<sup>` elements style with CSS so they would look like regular text. I cannot *unwrap* superscript elements in my HTML.

In other words the output of

```
<div>Some <sup>random</sup> text.<div>
```

should look exactly like

```
<div>Some random text.<div>
```

How can I achieve this, please? Should I try to counter the effects of the superscript, or is there a smarter way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the `sup` tag inherit its `font-size` and `vertical-align` from its parent (the `div`).

```css
sup {
  font-size: inherit;
  vertical-align: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div>Some <sup>random</sup> text.<div>
```

This will work even if the parent has had more styles applied to it.

```css
div {
  font-size: 10px;
}

sup {
  font-size: inherit;
  vertical-align: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div>Some <sup>random</sup> text.<div>
```

Comment: Or use the value `unset`, but that isn't supported by that many browsers yet. For these two properties, `inherit` will work fine.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Note that in some extreme circumstances, you will also need to reset the line-height. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/eoughfzb/1/), where the solution that doesn't reset the line-height isn't identical to the original. Only on Mozilla though.

Answer (score 3):

The sup tag uses font-size and vertical align to create the effect, you can reset this back to its initial values though.

http://jsfiddle.net/p4ohok7a/

```
sup {
    font-size: initial;
    vertical-align: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding following style for 'sup', you can do this.

```
sup{
  font-size: initial;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Here is the link for this code.
http://jsbin.com/zuhasoqide/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

According to [Mozilla](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/html.css), the default style for `sup` is

```css
vertical-align: super;
font-size: smaller;
line-height: normal;
```

so those are the three properties you'll need to reset.